# Sony Vegas: is this possible?

Tags: sony-vegas

When cutting a selection in Vegas, is it possible that it auto-joins the scenes?
I mean instead of leaving an empty space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "**Auto Ripple**."

Click on the auto ripple icon in the main toolbar or press Ctrl-L to toggle Auto Ripple on/off.

[image]

With Auto Ripple turned on, when you remove a clip from the time line, the clips that come after will automatically move to the left to fill in the space.

Video Tutorial: [Auto Ripple in Sony Vegas & Movie Studio](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwUxZbHTMpw)